# How to compare JSON with Test::Deep?

Tags: json, unit-testing, perl

When I run the following code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::Deep;
use Test::Deep::JSON;

cmp_deeply(json("{}"), json("{}"));
```

I get

```
Found a special comparison in $data
You can only use specials in the expects structure at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Test/Deep.pm line 348.
    Test::Deep::descend(Test::Deep::JSON=HASH(0x5559ec3b3810), Test::Deep::JSON=HASH(0x5559ecb236a8)) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Test/Deep.pm line 221
    Test::Deep::cmp_details(Test::Deep::JSON=HASH(0x5559ec3b3810), Test::Deep::JSON=HASH(0x5559ecb236a8)) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Test/Deep.pm line 202
    Test::Deep::cmp_deeply(Test::Deep::JSON=HASH(0x5559ec3b3810), Test::Deep::JSON=HASH(0x5559ecb236a8)) called at jsondiff.pl line 6
```

Why is that and how can I compare two JSON strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use Test::More tests => 1;

use Test::Deep;
use Test::Deep::JSON;

my $json_to_check = '{}';

cmp_deeply($json_to_check, json({}));
```

If you want to start with JSON, just decode it before passing it to `json`.

```
use feature qw( state );

use Test::More tests => 1;

use Test::Deep;
use Test::Deep::JSON;

use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( );

sub from_json {
   state $json = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new();
   return $json->decode($_[0]);
}

my $json_to_check = '{}';

cmp_deeply($json_to_check, json(from_json('{}')));
```

Comment: Why do you pass `{}` without any quoting to `json(...)`? Is this just an  hash reference (not JSON) that you convert into a JSON object? And then `Test::Deep::JSON` converts the scalar to JSON object automatically and compares it to the jsonified hash?

Comment: Backwards. It is a hash ref, but you're testing if the JSON matches the structure, because there's more than one way yo encode the same structure. For example, `{"a": "\n", "b":123}` is equivalent to `{"b":123, "a": "\u000a"}`. That's why wisely chose to use `cmp_deeply` rather than just comparing two JSON strings.